# How connect to the mongodb from localhost using docker on Linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, localhost

I have this line of code:

> const client = await MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017')

But I cant run http://localhost:3000 because the code is waiting the connection to the database to start listen to the 3000 port

I need to create a connection to the mongodb from localhost using docker, but dont know how

Comment: https://earthly.dev/blog/mongodb-docker/

Comment: Usefull stuff Chris, thanks! And I just found a video teaching how to connect to mongodb step by step, didnt know that need to create a docker volume and mount inside the container, exposes the port and so on, I just start on docker 

Comment: If helps someone else, here is the link: https://youtu.be/IYshLM8Oi4w